# Selecting features using expression with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute, select

How can I select features with PyQGIS using an expression?

I tried to use an `QgsExpression` but the select method doesn't take it:

```py
exp = QgsExpression("'ogc_fid' = 482")
cLayer = canvas.currentLayer()
cLayer.select(exp)
```

Is it possible and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Nowadays : QGIS 3.x

1. Get the layer reference:

```py
  layer = iface.activeLayer()
```

2. Select features by expression:

```py
  layer.selectByExpression("\"ogc_fid\"=482")
```

---

### Before QGIS 2.16

Follow these steps:

1. Get the layer reference:

```py
   cLayer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()`
```

2. Get a featureIterator from an expression:

```py
   expr = QgsExpression( "\"ogc_fid\"=482" )
   
   it = cLayer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
```

3. Build a list of feature Ids from the result obtained in 2:

```py
   ids = [i.id() for i in it]`
```

4. Select features with the ids obtained in 3:

```py
   cLayer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
```

---

*NOTE:* If you want to set an expression with a **string** value, you need to add quotation marks to such value, in this way:

```py
expr = QgsExpression( " \"name\" = 'my string' " )
```

If your string value comes from a variable, you can do this:

```py
myVariable = 'my string'
expr = QgsExpression( " \"name\" = '{}' ".format(myVariable) )
```

Comment: How do I say `"\"ogc_fid\"=482 AND name=\"hello world\""`? Here it says that this isn't available in python: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpression.html#a056130107ebe0f5afdf298b4a93c5ac2. Maybe you know of a way to circumvent this limitation?

Comment: Keep in mind that field names must be double quoted, string values single quoted, and numbers don't need quotes. In your example: `"\"ogc_fid\"=482 AND \"name\"='hello world'"`. BTW, the link you included in your comment is actually stating that the static attribute `BinaryOperatorText` is not available in Python bindings, but operators do work for `QgsExpression`, even if they're used through Python bindings.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo I'm using your method above but can't get it to return any values, despite having copy & pasted a known value to search for. The column contains strings, so I have used `expr = QgsExpression("\"police_ref\" = 'P0580996'")`. I have tried adding a break-character to the search term (for the single-quotes) but it doesn't make a difference. Interestingly, if I open the attribute table I'm querying, and use the expression builder there, it does make a selection if the police_ref I use as an example is in the very first row, but not otherwise

Comment: @GermánCarrillo sorry never mind that, I'm not sure what I did differently but I can get it to select features now! For others reading, you don't need a break-character for the single quotes

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me from the QGIS Python Console

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression(" \"ogc_fid\" = '{}' ".format(482))
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. The existing (and accepted) answer is far more complete. How does this improve upon that? Generally, the way to earn reputation points is to answer *unanswered* questions, but a new complete answer to a three year old question would be welcome if it specifically addresses a problem with the previous solution (in which case, the problem should certainly be mentioned).

Answer (score 3):

You only need to test it in the GUI interface: "Select by Expression". If it works, you can paste it in your Python code surrounded by double quotes `""`.

```py
exp = QgsExpression("ogc_fid=482")
```

If you compare to a string, you can add single quote `''`.

```py
exp = QgsExpression("ogc_fid='482'")
```

It's the same principle in Python, it can make the difference between double quote and single quote. More information can be found here: [Difference between quotation marks ('single' vs "double") in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301566/difference-between-quotation-marks-single-vs-double-in-qgis)