# Trying to use LIKE in an expression in pyQgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to select elements from a layer. The field I use is a string/character field. My code is as follows:

```
expr = QgsExpression(ur'"myField" = \'valueILookFor\'')
it = myLayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
ids = [i.id() for i in it]
myLayer.setSelectedFeatures (ids)
```

I do know that the error lies in the first line, as I've already used the rest of the code (which is from [stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/how-to-select-features-using-an-expression-with-pyqgis)) for selecting values.

Apparently this does not select any value. I have tried to replace the "=" with a "LIKE" without more success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use triple-quoted strings, this means you can leave your double quotes and single quotes (apostrophes) un-escaped.

Can make things a little tricky to maintain, so if you can, leave one space padding at the start and end, like so

```
expr = QgsExpression(""" "my_field" like '%something%' """)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
expr = QgsExpression( " \"myField\"= 'valueILookFor' " )
```

or

```
expr = QgsExpression( " \"myField\" LIKE 'valueILookFor' " )
```

Have to be careful with the quotes. Also, you can just use `u'string` instead of `ur'string'`.

Comment: Does not work either. I tried various combinaisons of these.

Comment: does it work with a triple quoted string? `expr = QgsExpression( """ "myField"= 'valueILookFor' """)`

Comment: @François - Apologies, I missed out the single quotes as it initially worked for numbers. Should work now for strings also.

Comment: @StevenKay - The triple quote method should also work, consider posting your comment as an answer =)

Comment: YES ! Thanks Steven, your method works ! Thanks a lot :) ! Post it so I can mark it as answered.