# AttributeError:'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'setSelectedFeatures' PyQGIS 3.0

Tags: select-by-attribute, pyqgis-3

What is the new expression of setSelectedFeatures in PyQGIS 3.0 ?
I wrote the following code:

```
def verCode(layername):
  layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]    
  selection= layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"CODE_MERC" is NULL'))
  layer.setSelectedFeatures([s.id() for s in selection])
  iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [pyqgis api documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=qgsvectorlayer#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.selectByIds) there is a method

```
layer.selectByIds([s.id() for s in selection])
```

And for some performance improvements and good practice, don't request any attributes or geometry, if you only need the feature id

```
request = QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression('"CODE_MERC" is NULL')).setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry).setSubsetOfAttributes([])
selection = layer.getFeatures(request)
```

Comment: Many thanks Matthias. It is very helpful. However, for the QgsFeatureRequest expression, I receive an error : TypeError: QgsFeatureRequest(): arguments did not match any overloaded call. Perhaps, I wrote it in the wrong way in my code. Could you please write it explicitly in my code?

Comment: It probably was an error on my side. Does it work if you do `QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression('"CODE_MERC" IS NULL')).setFlags(...`

Comment: No error but nothing happen. I am sorry, but I did not know where to place the obtained "request" in the code. Note that "request" expression is not attached to any layer.

Comment: I updated the sample, is it better now? Btw, nothing should change, it's just "good practice" to request only what is actually needed.