# Getting particular feature using expression in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute

How to get a particular feature using an expression in PyQGIS?

For example, there are 100 houses (with 100 entries in Attributes Table). I want to get only one house with field name (`"name"=="John's House"`)  and make get selected that feature in the map view.

Comment: Possible duplicate one more time: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/how-to-select-features-using-an-expression-with-pyqgis. Please take a few minutes to search the web or GIS Stack Exchange before you ask a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select features using an expression with pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/how-to-select-features-using-an-expression-with-pyqgis)

Comment: @wetland Possible duplicate of my comment ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer.selectByExpression('"name"=\'John's House\'', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)

selection = layer.selectedFeatures()

print(selection)
```

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#selecting-features)
- [Selecting features using expression with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/selecting-features-using-expression-with-pyqgis)