# Using Pyqgis 3 to select features from attribute table by expressions

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, pyqgis-3

I have a shp with the following attribute table:[image]

The column Line_ID represents each line (line 0, line 1, line 2 ... ).

The column ID are the points id (point 1, point 2 … ).

The column Declividad is the slope.

I need to find a specific slope break for each line. 
So, the way I’m thinking to do this is to check if the previous point has slope value less than 8 and if the posterior point has slope value more than 8. So the script should select the posterior point.

For example: line 0 / point 1 = slope 2 ;line 0 /  point 2= slope 1;line 0 /  point 3= slope 4; line 0 / point 4= slope 10. 
So the script, in this case, should select point 4, because it has slope value more than 8 and its previous point (point 3) has slope value less than 8.

How could I make this using Pyqgis?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/how-to-select-features-using-an-expression-with-pyqgis