# Selecting features by attribute containing string using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

Is it possible using Python to select all features whose attribute contain a specific string?

I am new to QGIS.

The layer has an address column ("Bauvorha_3") which looks like this:

```
Berlin, Am Alexanderplatz, ...

Berlin, Goethestrasse, ...

Hamburg, Alsterufer, ...

Hamburg, Reeperbahn, ...
```

I need to select all features containing for example "Hamburg" or "ufer".

place is the user-input string.
I've tried to use LIKE but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
place = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
place = str(place)
versuch = "'{}'".format(place)
search = '"Bauvorha_3" LIKE "{}%"'.format(versuch)
self.iface.activeLayer().selectByExpression(search)
```

Comment: Have you seen this topic [Selecting features using an expression with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/selecting-features-using-an-expression-with-pyqgis/131162#131162)?

Comment: Try: search = `""""Bauvorha_3" LIKE('%{0}%')""".format(place)`

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot @BERA !

Comment: Then accept my answer with the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
search = """"Bauvorha_3" LIKE('%{0}%')""".format(place)
```

You were missing enclosing () and % sign before keyword. And i
f you have alot of single and double quotes inside a string, enclosing everything in three double quotes usually work to make python understand what you want.

Comment: search = f""""Bauvorha_3" LIKE('%{place}%')"""