# Selecting features using two expressions with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I am selecting a river by expression. There are more than two rivers with the same name. So, I am thinking of using HUC. I found the following site about the expression:
[Selecting features using an expression with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131158/selecting-features-using-an-expression-with-pyqgis)
But I could not get a valid syntax if there are two expressions. My code is the following. How do I fix it?

```
layer.selectByExpression("\"PNAME\"='{}'".format(river_name)AND "\"HUC\" = '{}'".format(huc))
```

Comment: layer.selectByExpression(f"\"PNAME\"='{river_name}' AND "\"HUC\" = '{huc}'")

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it works 

layer.selectByExpression(f"\"PNAME\"='{river_name}' AND \"HUC\" = '{huc}'")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to list ids and select by them. I think the python syntax is easier to get right:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
field1 = 'kommunnamn'
field2 = 'lan_kod'

ids = [f.id() for f in lyr.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)) if f[field1]=='Ale' and f[field2]=='14']
lyr.select(ids)
```

[image]